# AS3 - addChild Error #1009 - IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling

I keep getting an Error #1009 because I'm trying to display an Alert Box using addChild inside of the ioErrorHandler function.

`trace("IOErrorEvent: " + event);` works fine. But I get the `Error #1009` inside of my Alert Box class.

```
////---- Display Alert Box 
private function displayAlertBox():void
{
    alertBoxContainer.x = stage.stageWidth - alertBoxBg.width >> 1;
    alertBoxContainer.y = stage.stageHeight - alertBoxBg.height >> 1;
    addChild(alertBoxContainer);
}
```

Here is my code. The Alert Box class works fine everywhere else except inside of the error event handler. Can you actually use addChild inside of an error event handler? I tried calling a function from inside of the error event handler to display the Alert Box class and that still didn't work.

```
//Display Alert Box
private var alert_Box:alertBox;

var _userIdRequest:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
_userIdRequest.load(new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/New_User_Id.php"));
_userIdRequest.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, CompleteHandler);
_userIdRequest.addEventListener(flash.events.IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

////--- Error Handler;
function ioErrorHandler(event:flash.events.IOErrorEvent):void 
{
    // not able to connect to the server
    trace("IOErrorEvent: " + event);

    alert_Box = new alertBox();
    addChild(alert_Box);
}
```

Comment: where is your function? is in the main class of your project or in a class of of object?

Maybe could be enough add your alert_Box object explicitly to the root with something like 

MovieClip(root).addChild(alert_Box);

Comment: I didn't add the function above. I tried a function and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I have 3 classes total:

splashScreen Class
consumerId Class
AlertBox Class

The main class that is loaded is the splashScreen class. Inside of the splashScreen class I call the consumerId class to create an id. If there's a problem with the url connecting to my server. The IOErrorEvent error is triggered and the AlertBox class is supposed to display from inside of the consumerId class. Well, after alot of testing. I can't load the AlertBox inside of the consumerId class. This is how I get the #1009 Error. Once I send a static function back to the slashScreen class from inside of the consumerId class's IOErrorEvent error handler. I can call the AlertBox class from inside of the splashScreen class and the Alert Box will display.

Answer (score 0):

I tried into new project and everything goes well.

I put this code into first frame. I'm using Flash CC

```
import flash.events.Event;

//Display Alert Box
var alert_Box:alertBox;

var _userIdRequest:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
_userIdRequest.load(new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/New_User_Id.php"));
_userIdRequest.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, CompleteHandler);
_userIdRequest.addEventListener(flash.events.IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

////--- Error Handler;
function ioErrorHandler(event:flash.events.IOErrorEvent):void {
    // not able to connect to the server
    trace("IOErrorEvent:");
    alert_Box = new alertBox();
    addChild(alert_Box);

    alert_Box.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
    alert_Box.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
} 

function CompleteHandler (e:Event):void {
    trace("complete!");
}
```

In my case **alertBox** is a square ... 
I think your alertBox class has problems did you add child twice?

Comment: I'm currently using Flash Builder 4.7. What I'm using is a subclass.